# C# to move mail to PST

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to use C# to access my Outlook Sent Folder and move the messages there to a folder in my PST called Archive.  This is the code I was working with, but I am getting multiple compile errors.  Does someone here with more coding experience know how to accomplish this?

```
static void MoveMe()
{
try
{
    _app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    _ns = _app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    _ns.Logon(null, null, false, false);
    Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
    Outlook.Items SentMailItems = SentMail.Items;
    Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
    foreach (object collectionItem in SentMailItems)
    {
        moveMail.Move(Archive);
    }
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    _ns = null;
    _app = null;
    _inboxFolder = null;
}
}
```

Error list from the comments:

1. `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`
2. `The type or namespace name 'Emails' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
3. `The name 'A_Sent' does not exist in the current context`
4. `The name 'moveMail' does not exist in the current context`
5. `The name 'SentMail' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: What are your errors?

Comment: 1) Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement 
2) he type or namespace name 'Emails' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3) The name 'A_Sent' does not exist in the current context
4) The name 'moveMail' does not exist in the current context
5) The name 'SentMail' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I had to flag this as off-topic because `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.`, because some of the issues you have are very basic (ie, where is `moveMail` defined, where is `SentMail` defined, etc) and are unrelated to your actual question at hand.

Comment: I dont see this as off topic at all.  He's got code that doesnt compile and is asking how to accomplish his task.  Yes, perhaps he should include his error in the body of the post and denote and tighten up his code a bit.  But it is not overly complicated code to be able to see past that.

Comment: You're clearly missing some code here.  I'd try adding `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;` at the top of your code, and adding the missing moveMail function that you seem to be referring to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is an example of how you would get the source folder (SentItems) and move them to a PST(Archive).

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; 

public void MoveMyEmails()
    {
        //set up variables
        Outlook.Application oApp = null;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder oSource = null;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder oTarget = null;
        try
        {
            //instantiate variables
            oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            oSource = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
            oTarget = oApp.Session.Folders["Archive"];
            //loop through the folders items
            for (int i = oSource.Items.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                move the item
                oSource.Items[i].Move(oTarget);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
        //release objects
        if (oTarget != null)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oTarget);
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
        if (oSource != null)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSource);
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
        if (oApp != null)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oApp);
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I really need to stop helping people with Rep 1 point, what a waste of my time!...

Comment: I try to follow your code, it give me COMExeption on
`oTarget = oApp.Session.Folders["Archive"];` with _object not found_
I know this is a very old post, but can you give me a help?

Comment: @Aferrercrafter replace Archive with the actual name of the PST folder.