# How can I update a Outlook PST file? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I'm trying to build an app that will backup all my PST files using Win-forms in C#.

I think there is a backup option in outlook but I want more control over the backup process.

My app works with `IO.File`, and I'm using a copy method but I have large PST files, and the copy method is just overwriting those files and making every backup take ages.

So, I want to try and update those files instead of overwriting them, any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the PST file using `IO.File` class, you can try manipulating the .pst files through Outlook Interop.

What I understand is, when backup is performed, you want to update the same PST file with new changes.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777975/2185245) is a post which has code for getting a source folder and moving to a PST store.

I do not know the exact nature of your requirements. I hope this helps you.